# Saving content to Django models fail -

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to save a form content to a model, but I always end up with three errors which lead to another

1. `editor.models.DoesNotExist: ContentModel matching query does not exist.`
2. `sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: editor_contentmodel.ref_id`
3. `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: editor_contentmodel.ref_id`

**model.py**

```
class ContentModel(models.Model):
    ref_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=120, default='1', unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("content", "ref_id")
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    template = "editor/home.html"

    try:
        json_content = ContentModel.objects.get(ref_id='1')
    except Exception:
        raise HttpResponseServerError

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContentFormModel(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ref_id_new = '1'
            form_data = form.cleaned_data.get('content')
            new_content, created = ContentModel.objects.get_or_create(content=form_data)
            if created:
                new_content.ref_id = ref_id_new
                new_content.save()
    else:
        form = ContentFormModel()

    context = {'content': json_content.content, 'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ContentFormModel(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ContentModel
        fields = ['content']
```

I am not sure whats wrong in the code.

Is it because the `ref_id` is a primary key?

**Update**

I am using Django 1.10 on Python 3

Comment: In the model, you say that ref_id must be unique. But when you're creating the object, you always set ref_id to 1.

Comment: so you mean I should remove `default='1'` in the `models.py`?

Comment: Yes--and also remove new_content.ref_id = ref_id_new. Because ref_id is a primary_key, django should assign unique values to the ref_id column every time you create a new row. You don't have to do that yourself.

Comment: @AlexL Yes! Tha worked. Post in your answer.

Comment: Yes, `update_or_create` should do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer:

Remove `default=1` and `new_content.ref_id = ref_id_new`. Because `ref_id` is a primary_key, django will assign unique values to the `ref_id` column every time you create a new row. You don't have to do that yourself.